# NaN in mapper - name 'nan' is not defined

Tags: python, nan

I do as below

```
mapper = {'a': 'b', 'c': nan, 'd': 'e',  nan : nan}
df['b'] = [ mapper[x] for x in df['a'] ]
df['b'].value_counts()
```

and

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-3862b2347ce7> in <module>()
NameError: name 'nan' is not defined
```

What's wrong? Is a mistake in coding or in file?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Python does not have a built-in name `nan`, nor is there a keyword.

It looks as if you forgot to import it; `numpy` defines such a name:

```
from numpy import nan
```

From the local name `df` I infer you are probably using pandas; pandas' documentation usually uses `np.nan`, where `np` is the `numpy` module imported with `import numpy as np`. See their [*10 Minute to pandas* intro](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) for example.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't define what the variable `nan` is, so Python raises a `NameError`. If you want to check whether a number is `NaN` (not a number), use `math.isnan(x)`, where `x` is a float.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case, maybe the same.  I didn't import or qualify nan, but np automatically translated None to nan in my matrix output.
I could either just use None and let numpy figure it out or import nan from numpy,  I didn't know where nan was in numpy, so i just used None and it worked. Possibly the better choice is to import numpy's nan- idk