# NameError: name 'nan' is not defined

Tags: python, pandas, list, nan, intervals

After I copy/paste a list of intervals taken from a column dataframe, a 'nan' entry is included, and the list looks exactly like the following one:

```
from pandas import Interval
inter=[Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'),nan]
```

but if I try to print it

```
print(inter)
```

I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'nan' is not defined
```

I tried to substitute 'nan' for 'np.nan' but it seems like that the presence of the 'nan' entry in the 'inter' list, which I repeat, I manually copied and pasted it from an existing one,
is a problem.
How should I solve this?

Comment: `print([Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'),np.nan])` works just fine for me

Answer (score 1):

Python does not have a built-in name *nan*, nor is there a keyword.

It looks as if you forgot to import it;
*numpy* defines such a name:

```
from numpy import nan
```

From the local name *df* I infer you are probably using pandas; pandas' documentation usually uses *np.nan*, where *np* is the *numpy* module imported with `import numpy as np`.
Reference: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38672695/nan-in-mapper-name-nan-is-not-defined/38672715)